# How to choose replacement motherboard for an HP G6-2225TU?

Tags: boot, cpu, motherboard, hp-pavilion

So long story short, My [G6 2225TU](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03587886#AbT0) stopped giving any display (Though it sometimes got to boot screen and then failed) and capslock key is blinking.

By seeing the HP blink code document [here](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01732674), I believe my CPU is not functional any longer as there is one blink between pauses.

So I assume that means I have to replace my motherboard but I have no idea how does one choose a motherboard for a laptop.

My Laptop's processer is intel i3-3110M.

How can I determine which motherboard will fit my laptop? Which specs should I be looking for while finding a replacement board?

Comment: The board will be specific to the notebook model; contact HP for compatible replacements, or try and find one for that exact notebook model on eBay.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Does that mean that I can't use this opportunity to get a better motherboard and have to get the one which just got fried? :(

Comment: Basically.  There may be a better one out there, but it too will be an HP for a variation of that same notebook line.  It will most likely only be slightly better, and if you're keeping the same everything else, changing motherboard model will offer no great improvements.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Okay thanks. I have left HP support a message but I really don't like their services and their forum so I was hoping SU might guide me better than they ever could. Anyhow, should I delete this?

Comment: Replacing notebook motherboards is pretty straight forward. You don't get the luxury of choosing from a lot of boards, because laptop motherboards are very proprietary. You're best off just getting the exact same motherboard and replacing it.